# Redirect in the resolver class not working

Tags: angular

I have the app based on the Angular 4.3.1
In this app, I have the protected route `/profile` that I'm trying to deny for the unauthorized users using Resolver.
My resolver checks UserService and, if there is no user info, should make the redirect to the main page. But redirect doesn't work. I'm getting no errors, so I have no idea, what can I look for in this situation.
As I found out, I'm loosing the context within the arrow function in the `Observable.create`. But then 2 new questions:
1. If `this` is the another object in the place where I'm calling `this.router`, why I'm getting no errors if this object doesn't have the `navigateByUrl` method?
2. Why I'm losing the context? I'm using the same way in the services, it always works without any problem, so why it doesn't work here?
Any ideas?

```
  public resolve(): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
      this.userService.getUserInfo().subscribe(
        () => {
          observer.next(true);
          observer.complete();
        },
        () => {
          console.error('Access to this section is denied for the unauthorized users');
          // I see this error, so I'm really here
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Method from the UserService

```
  public getUserInfo(force?: boolean): Observable<UserInfoModel> {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<UserInfoModel>) => {
      if (force) {
        this.loadUserInfo().subscribe(
          (userInfo: UserInfoModel) => {
            this.updateUserInfo(userInfo);
            observer.next(this.userInfo);
            observer.complete();
          },
          (error: ObservableErrorInterface) => {
            observer.error(error);
          }
        );
      } else if (this.userInfo) {
        observer.next(this.userInfo);
        observer.complete();
      } else {
        let observableError: ObservableErrorInterface = {
          description: 'User is not registered',
          error: null
        };
        observer.error(observableError);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: 1. why don't you use [canLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) guard? 2. Your piece of code seems valid, so either post the whole code or even better create a plnkr

Comment: Please post the whole code of the class and the code of userService.

Comment: Guards don't prevent page loading. Resolver gives the possibility to not drawing anything until answer will be received. Moreover, guards are calling before the resolvers.
Added the method from the UserService.